# SPFx - How to call function on button click event from ts file with React

Tags: spfx, spfx-webparts, react, function, button

How to call function from ".ts" file for button onClick event in tsx file?

[image]

**this is my function in ts file:**

```
public button_click(): void {
   alert("CLICKED!");
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Add a property to your `IAutoCompleteProps` interface for your click handler. Then pass the function from the AutoCompleteWebPart into the interface as one of the component's properties.

So in your IAutoCompleteProps something like this:

```
export interface IAutoCompleteProps {
  //Other properties
  clickHandler: () => void;
}
```

Then in your AutoCompleteWebPart render:

```
public render(): void {
    const element: React.ReactElement<IAutoCompleteProps > = React.createElement(
      AutoComplete,
      {
        //Other props
        clickHandler: this.button_click
      }
    );

    ReactDom.render(element, this.domElement);
}
```

Then in your AutoComplete component JSX portion:

```
<button onClick={this.props.clickHandler}>CLICK ME</button>
```

Comment: Is this the best way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the below sample which I have created using SPFx. Update the **Render** method and add a button with the onClick event in the **React tsx** file as shown below :

```
public render(): React.ReactElement<IReactGetItemsProps> {
 return (  

    <div className={styles.panelStyle} > 
      <br></br>

      <br></br> 
      <div className={styles.tableCaptionStyle} > Demo : Retrieve SharePoint List Items using SPFx , REST API  & React JS  </div>
      <br></br>
        <div >
        <button id="AlertMe"  type="submit" onClick={this.AlertMe} >AlertMe</button>
     </div>           
    </div>         
);  
}  
AlertMe()
{         
  alert("You have clicked Alert!");   
}
```

This adds the click event attribute to the button '**AlertMe**'. On clicking it, the **AlertMe** method is called. 
[image]

**Output :**

[image]